# Iterate on a Multiset in Java, use setcount() without ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, guava, multiset

```
Multiset<String> ngrams = HashMultiset.create();  
//added strings to the multiset...

    for (Entry<String> entry : ngrams.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getCount() > 3) {
          ngrams.setCount(terms, 3);
       }
    }
```

Throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`

How can I use `setCount()` without throwing this exception? Could some Java 8 code be useful here?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be modifying the `ngrams` set while you're iterating over it.

Comment: Create a new `Multiset<String>` with max 3 count per entry in `ngrams`.

Comment: Such exceptions pretty much mean to tell you to not modify some kind of collection WHILE you are iterating that very collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCount(E, int)` will only throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if the element count in the `HashMultiset` is zero.

i.e. If `ngrams` already contains `terms` then changing `terms` count will not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

e.g. You can add `terms` using a special count value (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) before iterating and then remove it after iterating if it wasn't changed:

```
Multiset<String> ngrams = HashMultiset.create();
//added strings to the multiset...

    ngrams.setCount(terms, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : ngrams.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getElement().equals(terms)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (entry.getCount() > 3) {
            ngrams.setCount(terms, 3);
        }
    }

    if (ngrams.count(terms) == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        ngrams.setCount(terms, 0);
    }
```

If your situation is more complicated then you'll probably be better off creating a new `Multiset<String>` as [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341054/iterate-on-a-multiset-in-java-use-setcount-without-concurrentmodificationexce#comment58389642_35341054) instead of modifying and iterating concurrently. (Or some other solution that doesn't involve concurrent iteration and modification, etc.)